# Actualizar recycler view items en Android

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

Tengo un `api` que me devuelve ítems por pagina, en este caso siempre le pido que me envíe 12 ítems, si los ítems recibidos son igual a 12 la pagina se incrementa sino se mantiene. Tengo el siguiente ejemplo en donde a mi `api` le envío la pagina 1 pero en este caso me devuelve 4 ítems los cuales muestro en mi `recyclerview`, luego de presionar mi botón de obtener mas datos me devuelve 6 ítems, es decir, los 4 anteriores y 2 mas. Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

Comparar los datos que me devuelve el `api` con los del `recyclerview` y solo agregar al mismo los ítems diferentes. Ejemplo:

```
primera llamada data -> A B C D se agregan al recyclerview
segunda llamada data -> A B C D E F 
comparar data de llamada 1 con llamada 2 y agregar E F porque son diferentes
```

En sí, el resultado a mostrarse en el `recyclerview` sería el siguiente: A B C D E F

Este es mi código:

```
mData.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mData.size());
notifyDataSetChanged();
//Con las 4 lineas anteriores elimino el boton final para agregar la nueva data
JSONArray res = response_json.getJSONArray("res");
for(int i=0;i<mData.size();i++){
    if(i >= row_index){ //row_index identifico el index de la pagina para actualizar a partir de él
        for(int j=0;j<res.length();j++){
            JSONObject item = res.getJSONObject(j);
            if(mData.get(i).getId() != item.getInt("id")){
                //Agregar datos diferentes
                obj = new Obj();
                obj.setId_pedido(item.getInt("id"));
                obj.setValor(item.getString("valor"));
                mData.add(obj);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
Obj mas = new Obj();
mas.setId_pedido(0);
mas.setValor("OBtener mas data");
mData.add(mas);
//Agrego el boton al final
```

Todo eso lo hago en mi adaptador porque el botón lo agrego siempre al final como ultimo ítem. Al ejecutarlo no funciona, mi `app` se cuelga, ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?. De antemano les agradezco

Comment: ¿Si la api devuelve todo, porque directamente no cambiar el dataset completo?

Comment: no porque la idea es mostrar los items desde la posicion donde se encuetran